# Netgear WNA3100M not seeing several networks

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Out of necessity, I am sharing my laptop's (Intel Centrino N-2230) wifi connection to all my devices.  My media center and two android phones are connected no problem, but my desktop (Netgear WNA3100M) simply doesn't see the network at all.  It also doesn't see another public wifi network I've used in the past (which is the strongest nearby Wifi network for all of my other devices), and a second public wifi network it will only connect to once in a blue moon (connects, but have only gotten past the browser login page once or twice, and always very slow).

I've tried forcing it to connect via the Netgear Genie app by entering in SSID and password of my laptop's wifi network manually, but I always get a failed to connect error.  I've tried changing the advanced settings for wifi config and wireless mode to the various options, but nothing changes, still does not see the two best networks.

In my Centrino N-2230 advanced settings, the only wireless modes listed are b/g, yet the Netgear is N only.  That shouldn't make a difference but I can't help but wonder.  Everything should be running on 2.4ghz as well, and nothing I have found on the web has worked thus far.

Thanks in advance if anyone has a solution...

Comment: Your centrino card is capable of 802.11b/g/n over 2.4Ghz only. Have you tried updating the drivers? Or digging a little bit deeper by gathering information about the problematic access points, like what encryption its using compared to access points you do not have issues with? (AES vs TKIP)

Comment: I just rebuilt both machines, so all drivers are the latest.

Unless there is something that I'm missing, it should work.  The fact that it doesn't see other networks, which are these public wifi networks that are actually someone else's router, tells me that it doesn't have anything to do with my laptop wifi adapter.  These other networks have no encryption; you connect, and then open a web page where you login (ie Starbucks).  But the Netgear only sees one of them, and will only rarely login to the other one.

Comment: I had been connecting to a little Vodafone mobile wifi, and it worked fine with that.